# Migrating from AIX to RHEL

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am moving a server from AIX to RHEL, which means running my application shell scripts into the RHEL server.

- Scripts have .ksh extension
- In our AIX server, default shell is KSH
- of course, shebang used in all the scripts is #!/bin/ksh

My question is, what could be the challenges we could be facing by running these .ksh scripts in RHEL? Are there any documentations stating any incompatibilities? I know that usual default shell in RHEL is bash, will this cause any issue if I run my .ksh scripts? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not just change the default shell to ksh?

Comment: ksh on RHEL will be the least of your concern, if your script use for instance `lsdev -C -c disk` you are likely to  rewrite them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can easily set `ksh` as the default shell on your RHEL install. More importantly, as long as your shell scripts have a `#!/bin/ksh` shebang and as long as you call them directly (`/path/to/script.ksh`) and not using something like `$SHELL /path/to/script.ksh` where `$SHELL` is set to a non-ksh shell, then they will be run as ksh scripts no matter what the default shell happens to be.

The more important question is whether the scripts will work as expected on a new operating system which will likely have at least some things in a different path.